# SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sharepoint

I am trying to manipulate SharePoint's default calendar to add, edit and delete items and use SQL Server as the data source rather than SharePoint's database. I have worked through the last two days of using SPList and SPListItems but I keep ending up at the same problem. Once a user clicks +add on SharePoint's calender UI, I want to be able to store that information from the user into SQL Server rather than SharePoint. I've looked through a bunch of MSDN libraries, blogs and other google searches and nothing turns up. If anyone has done something similar or can help point in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write an Event Receiver for the ItemAdding & ItemUpdating events and attach it to the List(in this case Calendar) and write the code to persist the data to your custom SQL DB.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx